# When i visit first time on wordpress website, its open another website automatically on first click

Tags: wordpress

**When I visit first time on WordPress website, its open another website automatically on first click anywhere, I don't know why its showing this **strong text****

Comment: You probably got a malware in your site. They might have passed from the theme or a vulnerable plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is better to have more details. But if this happened without any actions from your side, I would agree with [Michela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8548242/michela-durazzi) - it could be some malware on your website.

If you don't know what's going on under the hood, it is hard to cleanup the website completely.
As a first action, I can recommend you to check if your hosting provider have any **backups** for the website. It is possible that you will be able to restore to the point when the website was clean.

To clean the website by yourself, you can use various Malware Scanner plugins, like Wordfence or other specific. They can check for changes inside Wordpress core or standard repositories + they can check for strange, vulnerable and malicious parts of code. But be careful - if you have some custom code, it is better to check it with the code author.

If you'll be able to cleanup the website, I will highly recommend to go harden the website security. Some classic recommendations may be found in the official documentation - https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/.